# Fail of bash script with flock

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, flock

I have a task: Calling a script by curl every ten seconds.

For that I do:

1. Create bash-script: admin_cron.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while :; do
       sleep 10
       flock -n /var/www/admin/data/cron_lock -c \
           'curl -m 3 "http://url.com/?mod=kasdim_robot_cron&server=true"' &
   done
   ```
2. Add rule in crontab:

   ```
   */1 * * * * flock -n /var/www/admin/data/admin_lock -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   ```

So, cron will start `admin_cron.sh` every minute if the file `admin_lock` is free. Then, if `admin_cron.sh` is terminated or dies, `admin_cron.sh` starts again. It's ok.

`admin_cron.sh` tries to call every 10 sec my URL through curl. Max time for curl is three seconds.

Problem: when I start, everything works fine for about two to three days; after, I see in the `htop` util that `admin_cron.sh` is hover process:

1. at start time:

   ```
     CPU[                                                                             0.0%]   Tasks: 61, 53 thr; 1 running
     Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||461M/996M]   Load average: 0.44 0.83 0.94
     Swp[                                                                            0K/0K]   Uptime: 86 days, 18:43:58

     PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
     707 root       20   0 29600  2828  2512 S  0.0  0.3  1:27.18 ├─ /usr/sbin/cron -f
   22150 root       20   0 48868  2864  2416 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  └─ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
   22151 admin      20   0  4288   720   648 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │     └─ /bin/sh -c flock -n /var/www/admin/data/admin_lock -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   22156 admin      20   0 10044   816   728 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │        └─ flock -n /var/www/admin/data/admin_lock -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   22161 admin      20   0  4288   764   692 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │           └─ /bin/sh -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   22167 admin      20   0 11132  2896  2648 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │              └+ /bin/bash /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   ```
2. After some time:

   ```
     CPU[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   Tasks: 64, 53 thr; 2 running
     Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||466M/996M]   Load average: 1.00 1.00 1.00
     Swp[                                                                            0K/0K]   Uptime: 86 days, 18:42:30

     PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
     707 root       20   0 29600  2828  2512 S  0.0  0.3  1:27.18 ├─ /usr/sbin/cron -f
   25818 root       20   0 48868  2864  2416 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  └─ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
   25819 admin      20   0  4288   752   676 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │     └─ /bin/sh -c flock -n /var/www/admin/data/admin_lock -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   25821 admin      20   0 10044   800   712 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │        └─ flock -n /var/www/admin/data/admin_lock -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   25824 admin      20   0  4288   788   716 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │           └─ /bin/sh -c /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   25825 admin      20   0 12636  4260  2552 R 98.7  0.4 60h56:25 │              └─ /bin/bash /var/www/admin/data/admin_cron.sh
   ```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Why is the script running `flock` in the background?

Comment: because, I need to call script and get answer and only after that plus 10 sec run it again

Comment: Shouldn't you redirect the output of `curl` somewhere?

Comment: The problem you're having seems like the `sleep` is being skipped for some reason. Not sure why, though.

Comment: Why process run at 98.7%? In my script possible three commands: sleep, flock and curl. One of them is fail all. Which and why?

Comment: I said I'm not sure why. Maybe you should add some code to print out the time after each statement, to see what's happening.